# Issue with jQuery/CSS transitions between slides disrupting position:fixed performance inside slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm working on 'page' style transitions between elements on a page. [My approach is pretty much this](http://jsfiddle.net/tb2H3/) which works fine but when I put something with position 'fixed' inside one of the 'pages' the functionality just isn't happening - its working more like absolute positioning. The code is basically..

```
<nav id="navigation-bar">
    <!-- Content Goes Here --->
</nav>

#navigation-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Does anyone know if theres a solution to this? Or if not a possible alternative? If you position the navigation bar outside of the 'page' it works but I'm not sure how to link the #navigation-bar to 'transition' at the same time/style as the slide I also think this makes things more complicated - there is also an element on the mobile view that needs to be in the page to work that is also position fixed and I need an approach that essentially works with positioning the html inside the panel/page but can be positioned fixed and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way `position:fixed` works extract the element of all the DOM.

> An element with position:fixed is fixed with respect to the viewport. It stays where it is, even if the document is scrolled.

On other side `position:absolute` is able to extract the element but position it relative to another containing block.

> Whereas the position and dimensions of an element with position:absolute are relative to its containing block, the position and dimensions of an element with position:fixed are always relative to the initial containing block. This is normally the viewport: the browser window or the paper’s page box. To demonstrate this, in the example below you will make one of your elements fixed. You will make the other one very tall in order to cause a scrollbar, to make it easier to see the effect it has.

So if you have one element with fixed position inside each `div` it doesn't matter because is extracted and positioned in relation to the primary container. Then the best you can do is work with `position:absolute`.